# Change timestamp format in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, timestamp, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to change the format of a timestamp in AWS Athena but I am not able to get it correct, would someone please help?

The value (Data format: string (Partitioned)) of the column I am trying to change is
20220826T073200Z
and I would like the output to be
2022-08-26 07:32:00

Comment: What is the type of column? `varchar`?

Comment: Apologies, should obviously have included that. Its a string (Partitioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse date first, for example with [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html):

```sql
select date_parse('20220826T073200Z', '%Y%m%dT%H%i%sZ');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-08-26 07:32:00.000 |

If this is not good enough you can format it with `date_format`:

```sql
select date_format(date_parse('20220826T073200Z', '%Y%m%dT%H%i%sZ'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-08-26 07:32:00 |